# SSMS 2008 vs SSMS 2005 Object Explorer differences

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been using Microsoft SSMS for many years and just got upgraded to the 2008 client from 2005.  I have run into a problem with the Object Explorer Detail window when looking at a list of my views.  I typically will sort this screen by the create date to bring my most recent views to the top, but in this new 2008 client, I don't seem to have that option.  The only items in the header are "Name" and "Policy Health State" (what ever that is).  If I right click on the header, I still only see those two as options.  I called a coworker who also just had to make that change and he sees all the same options he did before, so I know it's a setting somewhere, but I don't know where to look.
[image]

Please help if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the Views folder selected in the Object Explorer window?

If I select the Views folder in the Object Explorer in SSMS 2008R2 and 2012, I am able to see the "Create Date" column in the Object Explorer Details.
[image: SSMS 2012]

Since you can only see the "Name" and "Policy Health State" columns, that sounds like you have a specific View selected in the Object Explorer, not the entire Views folder.

Comment: Well this is frustrating...I can't figure out how to upload a screen shot.  Yes, I have views selected in the left panel and my right panel looks very similar to yours, except there are only two columns as I state above and right clicking does not present anything beyond what I mentioned above.  

Can you tell me how to upload an image to a message.  Doing a search on Google says to click the image button, but there is no image button.

Comment: @CharlieRC If you edit your original question, you'll be able to see an icon that looks like a picture of a mountain (next to the {} icon). Click that and you can drag & drop a picture into your question.

Comment: Thank you Daniel T.  I have added the screen shot. As you will see, there does not seem to be an option to add the create date or modified date.  Either one would work for me, but I would prefer to have modified date.

Comment: I have modified the original message to show what I see if I right click on the header.  I asked a co worker (hitting same SQL server) to check this out on their machine and they see create date as an optional column and much more to the point, they do not see the "Health State Policy" at all.